# android make soft keyboard always visible

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

My activity has an EditText field and I want Soft Keyboard to be always visible in the activity. I set

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
```

in the manifest, but it results in animated appearance of Soft Keyboard when the activity starts. I need SoftKeybard to appear in full size at exactly the same time when activity starts, without animation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.

You can make the keyboard to automatically show when the activity or fragment is created but the keyboard will be dismissed when the user presses the backbutton.